# Scroll position not being detected good enough

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a part of code that looks if a user is scrolling up or down, and inside that check if the user is at the top of the page.

To see my position I log that position in my console but for some reason when I scroll up using my scroll wheel fast, it shows a number like 75, 98, 66 etc. Only when I scroll again (while it's already at the top) it goes to 0. Why?

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
  if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(height);
    if(height  > 20) {
        $('.nav-link').css('color', '#2f323a');
    }else{
        $('.nav-link').css('color', '#ffffff');
    }
  }
});
```

I want to change the text color of my menu to white when a user is at the top but now if I scroll up fast using my mouse scroll it does not work right away.

Comment: Hello @twan, maybe try to attach the "onscroll" event ?
I don't know if the "mouseweel" correspond to the "vanilla" one that is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousewheel_event

Comment: @OOM Yeah answer below fixed it. The bug was probably because part of my code is deprecated like you said.

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you want to detect any kind of scroll? Not just mouse wheel.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 20) {
            $('.nav-link').css('color', '#2f323a');
        } else {
            $('.nav-link').css('color', '#ffffff');
        }
    });
});
```